# Undefined variable error while trying to display the result of searched data from one php file to another php page's "div"

Tags: php, html

I want to make search page where I want to display my searched data from database in a "div"?I made a connection with database and searched for data in one phppage and created a div tag in another phppage.how can i display the searched data of one php page to be displayed in another php page's "div"

Searchdata.php:    `<div><form action="Search.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search"> 
<input type="submit" value="Search"></form>
<div><?php echo $data ?></div></div>`

Search.php:

```
<?php include 'connect.php';$data = '';if(isset($_POST['submit'])){$searchkey= $_POST['search'];   $searchkey=preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchkey); $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM newentry WHERE Date LIKE '%$searchkey%'")or die("Could not search!");$count = mysqli_num_rows($query); if(!($count == 0)) {    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ $Date=$row['Date'];$Entry=$row['Entry'];$data = '<div>'.$Date.'<br>'.$Entry.'</div>';}} else {$data = "There was no search result!";}}include 'searchdata.php';?>
```

I tried to display the result of search.php by storing the result in "data" in search.php and displayed in searchdata.php by giving  ..
It is showing an error of undefined variable:data in searchdata.php

Comment: ask your class mate https://stackoverflow.com/users/8848771/yo-yo

Answer (score 0):

The form action should be Searchdata.php. Searchdata is calling Search.  if search is called without searchdata then you will get the error.

```
<form action="Searchdata.php" method="post">
```

not

```
<form action="Search.php" method="post">
```

Comment: how can we give form action="searchdata.php" in the same page searchdata.php...i think its wrong

Comment: because it calls the php first the include is below the code so it runs the php then calls the form each time. try it it works fine.

Comment: so should i run the searchdata.php first or th search.php first....can you give me a brief code on this problem please

Comment: Go to the searchdata.php thats all.  the php code is only active upon submit.... so if no submit it only reads the include. so in going to searchdata first is calling only the include. at the bottom of your code, but after submit the php kicks in and then reads the include processing the form and echoing results.  Hope this helps.

Comment: the include at the end of your php code should be Search.php. The action in the form is above

Answer (score 0):

In your searchdata.php replace the php code from

```
echo $data
```

to

```
if(isset($_GET['data'])) echo $data;
```

Then on your search.php replace

```
include 'searchdata.php';
```

to

```
header("location: searchdata.php?data=".$data);
```

Note: This is only to fix your current problem which is passing of $data variable. There are still many issues on your code.

Comment: can i know what are those issues..because your solution isn't working for me